# Crystal Report in Local

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

Basically I want that my crystal report, if the project is moved to another folder, keeps working without changing the code.
Thats the code right now in my WinForm

```
ReportDocument cryRpt = new ReportDocument();
cryRpt.Load(@"Z:\Tempesta\Area Progetto\Area_Progetto_13_03_2014\Area_Progetto_27_02_2014\Area_Progetto_DATA_MAGAZINE\Data_Magazine\Data_Magazine\CrystalReport1.rpt");
crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt;
crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you tried to change the project folder yet and rerun this code?

Comment: Yes I did, it doesnt work

Comment: Ok then the only thing I would do is to use a path like \\servername\c$\..... just because if a client doesn't have the z: set, o set to another letter it won't work. And maybe I would put the path inside the configuration file. so if you move your reports you don't have to redeploy the entire application.

Comment: Could you write the code you would use? I cant understand that much without a good example. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Switch to using partial paths, also called relative paths.

Example:

"../partialPath/" + ReportName

Or use a variable to store the first have of the path and the report name.

pathVariable + "/partialPath/" + ReportName

Comment: "../partialPath/"  whats before /partialPath/ ?

Comment: It is the operating systems indicator for the previous folder or directory. A form of relative path. http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/

Comment: "Data_Magazine/partialPath/" + ReportName would work?

Comment: The final result of the concatenations needs to be a valid file system path. That will depend on your operating system. I think "./Data_Magazine/partialPath/" + ReportName is what you are looking for. If you want to use the current folder that is selected. "../Data_Magazine/partialPath/" + ReportName for the parent folder to be the reference point.

Answer (score 0):

Use relative paths like ../yourPath 
or you can use the enviroment variable like %programfiles% 
in the class `Enviroment`

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1h5xxewc.aspx for a better trattation of the class Enviroment

Comment: I didnt understand that one that much tbh.

Comment: for not specify a complete path of the rpt file you have to use a relative path, like that other people suggest.
To obtain that you can use differnt approach.

For example you can put the rpt file in a directory inside the program file directory ad access it via %programfiles%\YourFolder\YourRptFile.rpt

Answer (score 0):

Copy Your Report To Output path and use  `Application.StartupPath + "\\CrystalReport1.rpt"`

Comment: cryRpt.Load(Application.StartupPath + "\\CrystalReport1.rpt"); This one doesnt work. ( I enabled the copy to output option )